# Valid jquery code not working - parent/child problem

Tags: jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/gq6En/78/

In this fiddle, if you drag the orange box into the white box, the lime and black box will fade out. However, the lime box will not fade back in, even though the (apparently valid --according to JSLint) code instructs it to.

1) Does the lime box not fade back in because it is a child of the black box, and the parent black box has disappeared?

2) Is there a way to make the child lime box reappear without making the parent black box visible?

Comment: BTW code can be syntactically valid and do nowhere near what is expected or desired. My code seems to be doing this all the time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, `#black` has `display: none;` which inherits to all descendants — among these, `#lime`.
2. Yes, if you reattach it outside of the `#black` element. It can *never* be visible when it is a descendant of an invisible element.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gq6En/95/) replaces…

```
$("#lime").fadeIn(1000);
```

…with…

```
$("#lime").insertAfter("#black").fadeIn(1000); // Reattach after `#black`. This will manipulate the DOM!
```

…in order to prove points 1 and 2 :)

Comment: thank you very much. So once the DOM is manipulated this way, the child is forever independent of the parent? Do I have to use .append to make it a child again later?

Comment: @Micahel I'll help you out here - you could do this by issuing `$('#black').append($('#lime'));` - you'd use `.prepend()` if you wanted it to be the first child.

Comment: @Michael Yes, do what @melee said above :) I wasn't near a computer yesterday evening. A word of advice: use an inspector (e.g., Firebug for Firefox) when playing around with the DOM. It will always tell you the *current* state.

Answer (score 2):

1.) Yes - you can test this by adding the `#black` div to the second selector:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this)
                .addClass ("ui-state-highlight")
                .find ("p")
                .html("dropped");
            $("#lime, #black").fadeOut(1000, function(){ // Only #black needed here
            $("#lime, #black").fadeIn(1000); // Only #black needed here as well
            });
```

This brings the `#lime` back (along with the black, unfortunately).

2.) I'm not sure how to attack this because of the logic you're trying to put in place, but you might need to change the `#black` attributes to nothing (change the class while it is hidden by making it transparent or something) and fade it back in, giving the appearance that it went away?

Comment: good idea for workaround, thank you, but i'll give the accepted answer to the other answer, which used insertAfter as a way to escape the parent/child problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @Michael understandable! At least you have options :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it without fading the #black back in to.
You can, however, change the background of #black to none before you fade it back in and fade #pink out.
I've edited your fiddle/

Is this what you're looking for;
http://jsfiddle.net/gq6En/93/

Comment: o.k, thank you, great idea! I would use it, but there is a way to free the child from the parent. see answer by jensgram above.